# Firebase emulator is stoping with error: Pub/Sub Emulator has exited with code: 1

Tags: firebase, emulation, firebase-tools

Firebase emulator is stopping with the following error

```
!  pubsub: Fatal error occurred:
   Pub/Sub Emulator has exited with code: 1,
   stopping all running emulators
```

I don't know what is happening with emulator, even though I installed java and node correctly as said in the firebase documentation

Here is my firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the error by updating the JAVA_HOME variable in system environment variables and restarted the computer.